# Platform specific return types in Xamarin

Tags: c#, xamarin, xamarin.android

Suppose I need to implement some platform specific code in Xamarin, but there's a return type that's specific to the platform that I need to interpret. How would you do this? I've tried writing an interface for the type but I can't seem to make it work.

**IAuthService.cs**

```
namespace MyApp.Interfaces
{
    public interface IAuthService
    {
        Task<IUser> signInWithEmailAndPassword(string email, string password);
    }

    public interface IUser
    {
        string DisplayName { get; }
        string PhoneNumber { get; }
        string Email { get; }
        string Uid { get; }
    } 
}
```

**AuthService_Droid.cs**

```
[assembly: Dependency(typeof(AuthService))]
namespace MyApp.Droid
{
    public class AuthService : IAuthService
    {

        public async Task<IUser> signInWithEmailAndPassword(string email, string password)
        {
            FirebaseAuth auth = FirebaseAuth.Instance;

            IAuthResult result = await auth.SignInWithEmailAndPasswordAsync(email, password);

            IUser user = result.User;

            return user;
        }
    }
}
```

When trying to assign `result.User` I see the error

> Cannot implicitly convert type 'Firebase.Auth.FirebaseUser' to
>   'MyApp.Interfaces.IUser'. An explicit conversion exists (are
>   you missing a cast?)

Is this possible or can you only send basic types across platforms?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

in your shared code,

```
public class MyUser : IUser {
  ... implement properties ...
}
```

then in your platform code

```
IUser user = new MyUser() {
  DisplayName = result.User.DisplayName,
  ... assign other properties from result.User ...
};
```

Comment: Thanks Jason - easy!